# Python/Tweetpy - Usuario Not Found

Tags: python, twitter-api, tweepy

Estoy viendo como extraer datos de Twitter con Python y Tweetpy sin embargo cuando pongo cualquier usuario en la lista no me los encuentra. ¿Me estoy equivocando en el método?. Es el siguiente:

```
for handle in handles_list:
    print ('Fetching @' + handle)
    try:
        user = api.get_user(handle)
        followers = user.followers_count
        description = user.description
        for friends in user.friends():
            print (friends.screen_name)
        insert_db(handle, followers, description)
    except:
        print ('--' + handle + ' not found')
```

La lista donde busco es la siguiente:

```
handles_list = ["RISEtoWIN", "Nirvana", 'mudhoney']
```

Y como resultado (a pesar que existan) es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Y si tratas usando el screen name explícitamente:

```
>>> user = api.get_user(screen_name = 'Nirvana')
```

[get_user()](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_user) se supone que le pases un `id` pero para evitar ambiguedades puedes especificarlo

Edit:

Checa también el nivel de permisos que tiene tu aplicación en el [dashboard](https://apps.twitter.com/), igual y se te paso un permiso, yo la tengo configurada así: [image: Permisos de la app]

Comment: No, sucede lo mismo.